# A-frame pause/play animation mixer

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

I am wondering how I can use the  animation-mixer property of the Aframe extras component to pause/play an animation. I currently have a gltf model of a bird in my scene with an animation. What I'd like to do is when the pause button is clicked, a function is issued and the animation will pause, and when the play function is triggered, the animation will continue from **where it left off**. How can this be done? Current code:

```
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script>

function pause() {
//pause the animation
}

function play() {

//play the animation
}</script>
<button onclick="pause()" style="z-index: 10000000; position: fixed; margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer;">
Pause
</button>
<button onclick="play()" style="z-index: 10000000; position: fixed; margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 50px;">
play
</button>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.global/815f53ca-b7db-40aa-8843-e718abdfbf6d/scene%20-%202022-01-16T183239.246.glb?v=1642386788500" position="20 0 -35" rotation="0 90 0" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" animation-mixer="clip:Take 001; loop:10000000000000000000; timeScale: 1; crossFadeDuration: 1"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I read about a possible solution posted on github by **donmccurdy** yet I'm unsure of how I can get this into my code in a way that functions. Link to the post: https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/issues/222

Link to fiddle with code: https://jsfiddle.net/AidanYoung/0eufcg52/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don's solution is based on changing the `timeScale` which is used as a scaling factor for playback speed ([docs](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders#animation)):

```
// grab the entity reference
const el = document.querySelector("a-entity")
// pause - run at 0 speed
el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {timeScale: 0});
// play - run at normal speed(1)
el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {timeScale: 1});
```

---

Applied to Your code:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function pause() {
    document.querySelector("a-entity").setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
      timeScale: 0
    });
  }

  function play() {
    document.querySelector("a-entity").setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
      timeScale: 1
    });
  }
</script>
<button onclick="pause()" style="z-index: 10000000; position: fixed; margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer;">
Pause
</button>
<button onclick="play()" style="z-index: 10000000; position: fixed; margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 50px;">
play
</button>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.global/815f53ca-b7db-40aa-8843-e718abdfbf6d/scene%20-%202022-01-16T183239.246.glb?v=1642386788500" position="20 0 -35" rotation="0 90 0" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" animation-mixer="clip:Take 001; loop:true; timeScale: 1; crossFadeDuration: 1"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Model by [NORBERTO-3D](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/phoenix-bird-844ba0cf144a413ea92c779f18912042)(CC Attribution)